# Windows Phone 8 - Creating a web-style form with XAML

Tags: c#, forms, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm creating a Windows Phone 8 app that has a login form, where you enter a username and password.

```
<TextBlock Text="username"/>
<TextBox x:Name="UsernameText"/>

<TextBlock Text="password"/>
<PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordText"/>
```

I want to be able to present a similar experience to a web form, where pressing a "next" button or the Return key on the keyboard will jump from the first form field to the next. Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: @HighCore I wanted to use a <Form> tag, that would be the simplest, but that doesn't exist. Right now I have the fields chained to each other in the code behind when the Enter key is pressed. Not sure if I need to change the keyboard context, or what the best approach would be

Comment: Recommendation: forget HTML, it is laughable compared to XAML. XAML is very different from the multiple horrible hacks you need to do anything useful in HTML (javascript or whatever). The best approach to XAML-based technologies is the MVVM pattern. I suggest you research on that, it will save you countless headaches.

Comment: @HighCore thanks for the advice, I'm actually using MVVM in the app. I'm just wondering if there is something I can add to my XAML that allows me to jump from one form field to another, similar to the "Previous/Next" button on the iPhone (like this: http://www.alexcurylo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BSKeyboardContsols.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in support for that.
You can add a KeyDown event handler to UsernameText:

```
private void HandleUsernameKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.PlatformKeyCode == 0x0A)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        PasswordText.Focus();
    }
}
```

A separate event handler is required for every TextBox (or you can decide which control should get focus based on sender parameter)

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, I was just hoping I could find a better option. Thanks :)